# Laravel Composer Update Error

Tags: symfony, laravel, composer-php

I am having this error when I am using composer update in cmd, it is stopping me from installing new plugins for my website.

```
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","me
ssage":"Class 'Illuminate\\Validation\\ValidationExtensionServiceProvider' not f
ound","file":"C:\\Users\\noriel.mercado\\Desktop\\Xampp\\htdocs\\ofw\\vendor\\la
ravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\ProviderRepository.php","line":15
7}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned
with an error
```

and when I run my program or view it, laravel returns this error.

```
Class 'Illuminate\Validation\ValidationExtensionServiceProvider' not found
```

I really need some help, is there anyone there knows how to fix it?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload -o && artisan clear-compiled` should do the job.

Comment: after that, will i be able to user composer update?

Comment: it is still the same, it's not working, I still get the error

Comment: Maybe try deleting the vendor directory and running `composer update`